# Linear isomorphism between vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading a proof and don't understand the following part. Take a linear bounded functional $f:X\rightarrow R$ such that $f\neq 0 $. ($X$ is a Hilbert space and $R$ is the reals) Why is it that there is an isomorphism between $X / \textrm{ker}f$ and $\textrm{Im} f$?

Comment: What are $X$ and $R$? Do you know the first isomorphism theorem?

Comment: It's just the first isomorphism theorem from linear algebra: if $T:V\to W$ is linear, then $V/\ker T \cong {\rm range}\,T$. If $f\neq 0$ then $f$ is onto, so $X/\ker f\cong \Bbb R$. The fact that $X$ is a Hilbert space is irrelevant here.

Comment: @IvoTerek Thank you. I didn't know that.